# how to access module.export data in file from nested require

Tags: node.js

as node has evolved, a lot of the answers to similar questions are now not relevant, I would like to get an update suggestion based on node 4.15.5

assuming the following file structure

```
//file structure
|-common.js
|-config.js
|-local.js
|-server.js
```

`common.js`

```
var Common = {
  CONFIG: require("./config"),
  LOC: require("./local")
};
module.exports = Common;
```

`config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  http: {
    port: 8082,
    wsPath: "/server",
    wsPingInterval: 25000,
    wsPingTimeout: 5000,
 }
};
```

if I add the call to data in a script  `local.js` using a direct require and call `test()` the values are available as expected

```
var CONFLE = require("./config");
async function test(){
  return CONFLE.http.port;
}

module.exports = {
  test
}
```

`server.js`

```
 // from server.js -> test() returns 8082
 var COM = require("./common");
 COM.LOC.test();
```

however if I now use a `common.js` file to store all the required files and call the same data but via a nested notation I get an error

```
//file structure
|-common.js
|-config.js
|-local.js
|-server.js
```

`common.js`

```
var Common = {
  CONFIG: require("./config"),
  LOC: require("./local")
};
module.exports = Common;
```

`config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  http: {
    port: 8082,
    wsPath: "/server",
    wsPingInterval: 25000,
    wsPingTimeout: 5000,
 }
};
```

change `local.js`

```
var COM = require("./common");
async function  test(){
  return COM.CONFIG.http.port;
}

module.exports = {
  test
}
```

ERROR

```
Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'CONFIG' of module exports inside circular dependency
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

Am I using the `common.js` correctly or is there a better option?

Comment: Can you share full contents of config.js and server.js files?

Comment: Also share the full content of common.js beacuase this `Common = { CONFIG: require("./config") }` is not enough. Also have you tried `console.log(COM)` in local.js?